# What are functional unit and control logic of a cpu?

Tags: cpu-architecture

From the book [Modern Operating systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013359162X);

> The abundance of transistors on a single chip is leading to a problem: what to do with all of
>   them?
>
> We saw one approach above: **superscalar architectures**, with multiple **functional units**. But as the number of transistors increases, even more is possible. One
>   obvious thing to do is put bigger caches on the CPU chip. That is definitely hap-
>   pening, but eventually the point of diminishing returns will be reached.
>
> The obvious next step is to replicate not only the **functional units**, but also
>   some of the **control logic**. The Intel Pentium 4 introduced this property, called
>   **multithreading or hyperthreading** (Intel’s name for it), to the x86 processor, and
>   several other CPU chips also have it—including the SPARC, the Power5, the Intel
>   Xeon, and the Intel Core family. To a first approximation, what it does is allow the
>   CPU to hold the state of two different threads and then switch back and forth on a
>   nanosecond time scale. (A thread is a kind of lightweight process, which, in turn,
>   is a running program; we will get into the details in Chap. 2.)

A superscalar architecture is given in a previous figure 1-7(b):
[image]

I wonder what a functional unit and a control logic in a cpu mean?

Does a superscalar architecture also replicate control logic?

Are "functional unit" and "Execute unit" the same thing?

Is "control logic" the same as "Fetch unit" and "Decode unit"?

I am hesitant to answer yes to the above questions because of the following reasons.
The text says superscalar architectures replicate the functional units, while multithreading replicates not only the functional units, but also the control logic.

- But in figure 1.7(b), the superscalar one have multiple fetch and decode units besides multiple execute units, so I am not sure if "control logic == fetch and decode units" and "functional unit == execute unit".
- Also by multithreading, the text actually means time-multiplex. I don't know how replicating control logic is necessary for time-multiplex? Can't multiple threads or processes share the same control units (fetch unit and decode unit) at different times?

Comment: Doesn't the book define "functional unit"? If it doesn't find a better book.

Comment: no it doesn't. can you tell me what they are?

Answer (score 4):

#### Are "functional unit" and "Execute unit" the same thing?

Yes (in the context of how they are used in your book).

---

#### Execution unit

> In computer engineering, an **execution unit** (also called a **functional
>   unit**) is a part of a CPU that performs the operations and calculations
>   called for by the computer program. It may have its own internal
>   control sequence unit (not to be confused with the CPUs main control
>   unit), some registers, and other internal units such as a sub-ALU or
>   FPU, or some smaller, more specific components.[1]
>
> It is common for modern CPUs to have multiple parallel execution
>   units, referred to as scalar or superscalar design. The simplest
>   arrangement is to use one, the bus manager, to manage the memory
>   interface, and the others to perform calculations. Additionally,
>   modern CPUs' execution units are usually pipelined.

Source [Execution unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_unit)

---

#### Is "control logic" the same as "Fetch unit" and "Decode unit"?

Yes (in the context of how they are used in your book).

> The control unit is a component of a computer's central processing
>   unit (CPU) that directs operation of the processor. It tells the
>   computer's memory, arithmetic/logic unit and input and output devices
>   how to respond to a program's instructions.

...

> The Control Unit (CU) is generally a sizable collection of complex
>   digital circuitry interconnecting and controlling the many execution
>   units contained within a CPU.[citation needed] The CU is normally the
>   first CPU unit to accept from an externally stored computer program, a
>   single instruction, based on the CPU’s instruction set, then **decode**
>   this individual instruction into several sequential steps (**fetching**
>   addresses/data from registers/memory, managing execution [i.e. data
>   sent to the ALU or I/O], and storing the resulting data back into
>   registers/memory) that controls and coordinates the CPU’s interworks.

Source [Control unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit)

---

#### Central processing unit

> **Fetch**
>
> The first step, fetch, involves retrieving an instruction (which is
>   represented by a number or sequence of numbers) from program memory.
>   The instruction's location (address) in program memory is determined
>   by a program counter (PC), which stores a number that identifies the
>   address of the next instruction to be fetched. After an instruction is
>   fetched, the PC is incremented by the length of the instruction so
>   that it will contain the address of the next instruction in the
>   sequence.[d] Often, the instruction to be fetched must be retrieved
>   from relatively slow memory, causing the CPU to stall while waiting
>   for the instruction to be returned. This issue is largely addressed in
>   modern processors by caches and pipeline architectures (see below).
>
> **Decode**
>
> The instruction that the CPU fetches from memory determines what the
>   CPU has to do. In the decode step, the instruction is broken up into
>   parts that have significance to other portions of the CPU. The way in
>   which the numerical instruction value is interpreted is defined by the
>   CPU's instruction set architecture (ISA).[e] Often, one group of
>   numbers in the instruction, called the opcode, indicates which
>   operation to perform. The remaining parts of the number usually
>   provide information required for that instruction, such as operands
>   for an addition operation. Such operands may be given as a constant
>   value (called an immediate value), or as a place to locate a value: a
>   register or a memory address, as determined by some addressing mode.
>
> In some CPU designs the instruction decoder is implemented as a
>   hardwired, unchangeable circuit. In others, a microprogram is used to
>   translate instructions into sets of CPU configuration signals that are
>   applied sequentially over multiple clock pulses. In some cases the
>   memory that stores the microprogram is rewritable, making it possible
>   to change the way in which the CPU decodes instructions.

Source [Central processing unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit#Operation)

Comment: Thanks. do you mean that you think that functional unit and execute unit the same thing in the book? (note that I am not sure about if execute unit and execution unit are the same). what about control logic?

Comment: I've no idea as I've never read the book. Like I said before it doesn't sound like a very good book if it leaves such concepts undefined :/

Comment: @Tim What does the country of origin have to do with the book's contents? The book is considered *the* standard reference for operating systems. Also, have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_unit where it clearly says: *"The CU … decode[s] this … instruction … fetching addresses/data from registers/memory"*. You really should carefully read the material at hand. I am really worried about your latest questions, all of which show the same lack of research effort.

Comment: @slhck: My questions are more than what you thought. The text says superscalar architectures replicate the functional units, while multithreading replicates not only the functional units, but also the control logic. (1) But in figure 1.7(b), the superscalar one have multiple fetch and decode units besides multiple execute units, so I am not sure if "control logic == fetch and decode units" and "functional unit == execute unit".

Comment: (2) Also by multithreading, the text actually means time-multiplex. Why replicating control logic is necessary for time-multiplex? Can't multiple threads share the same control units (fetch unit and decode unit) at different times?

Comment: @Tim Your first bullet point question has already been answered by DavidPostill… control logic consists of fetching and decoding, and functional unit is equal to execute unit. That's clearly written above. As for the other point the most obvious explanation would be that you need multiple control units to fetch and hold data from different entry points. Don't count on the latter though—I have no reference at the moment.

Comment: @slhck; about the first point, does a superscalar architecture replicate  only functional units (i.e. execute unit) as said in the text, or both functional units (i.e. execute unit) and the control logic (i.e. fetch and decode units) as shown in figure 1-7(b)?

Comment: Downvoted: a few guesses and wikipedia quotes.  Plus I disagree with the guesses.  "Functional unit" and  "control logic" are generic/descriptive terms.  Examples of each does not mean that you can equate them.  I.E. an apple is a fruit, but not every fruit is an apple, so apples and fruit *"are not the same thing"*.

Comment: @sawdust the "probably yes" was in the context of what they mean in the OPs book (where they are apparently not defined).

Comment: If a fruit vendor only sells apples, that does not mean that fruit and apples *"are the same thing"*.  So even if the book uses the *category* "control logic" to refer to *specific* circuits, the OP and your answer are wrong to claim that they *"are the same thing"*.

Answer (score 1):

[image: diagram]

**Functional units of CPU**

1. Information from RAM sent along BIU which makes a copy and sends
   it to L2 cache.
2. **BIU** determines if the information is data or instruction. and sends it
   to appropriate L1 cache.
3. **CU** fetches instruction from instruction cache breaks it down into
   micro instructions before delivering to execution unit.
4. **Execution unit** consists of ALU, FPU or MMX (graphics/audio)
   It checks if data is needed, fetches data from L1 data cache → L2
   cache → RAM.

Comment: Please edit i am new to stackoverflow! :)